# get category link wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to echo category link of posts, so here is my query:

```
<?php
     $args=array(
          'cat' => 3,
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page' => 3,
          'caller_get_posts'=> 1
        );
       $my_query = null;
       $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
       if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
           while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                ....SOME HTML....

        <?php
              endwhile;
         }
      wp_reset_query();
   ?>
```

And on the bottom I need button "Show all posts" and it should redirect to subcategory list of post.

Comment: Get the Id of the post and use function get_the_category(post_id) to get categories, a post may belong to more than one category. Retrieve category id from the objects returned by get_the_category(), now use function get_category_link(cat_id) to get category link

Answer (score 0):

Just use Wordpress' function `the_category`. The second parameter `single` ensures that only child categories are shown. You can find more details about it in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category).
It should work, if you use the code below in your while loop.

```
<?php
 $postID = get_the_ID();

 the_category(', ', 'single', $postID);
?>
```

I hope this helps.